Use of ADDR Operator in MASM
In MASM, I want to send my variable num1 to a function and have it modify the original value num1 it is holding. I want to accomplish this by using addr operator. The output here need to be 6, instead of 2. But what I am getting is 2 despite trying to change the original value.
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword
include Irvine32.inc

.data
    num1 dword 2

.code
modify PROC var : DWORD
    mov eax, 6
    mov [var], eax
    ret
modify endp

main proc
    ; Call modify and pass the address of num1
    invoke modify, addr num1

    ; Print the updated value directly from num1
    mov eax, num1 ;Error, after the function call, num1 doesn't have the updated value of 6
    call WriteDec
    call Crlf

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp

end main


Use mov eax, [var]; mov dword ptr [eax], 6. As is, you are just overwriting the address passed as argument.

@Jester Thank you for the comment. I made the following changes as you suggested. But still get the value 2 instead of 6.
modify PROC var : DWORD     mov dword ptr[eax], 6     mov [var], eax     ret modify endp

That is not what I wrote.

What Jester was suggesting is this: https://pastebin.com/peC5m7zn

@MichaelPetch Thank you for making it very clear with all the comments. I really appreciate your help.
